# Take value from array which is in array

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this url:

> http://web.com/script.php?identifiers%5Bmc%5D%5Bnick%5D=name1&identifiers%5Bcs%5D%5Bnick%5D=name2&identifiers%5Bcs%5D%5Bpassword%5D=mypass

so i will get array like this:

```
[identifiers] => Array
    (
        [mc] => Array
            (
                [nick] => name1
            )

        [cs] => Array
            (
                [nick] => name2
                [password] => mypass
            )

    )
```

How do I take value `name1` and put into variable `$mc_name`?

Comment: Pretty basic: `$_GET['identifiers']['mc']['nick']`

Comment: $mc_name = $_GET['identifiers']['mc']['nick']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a simple array containing another array so you can simply specify multiple indexes for included array:

```
$mc_name = $_GET['identifiers']['mc']['nick'];
```

To better understand how it works think of it like assigning each array first to a variable like:

```
$identifiers = $_GET['identifiers'];
$mc_array = $identifiers['mc'];
$mc_name = $mc_array['nick'];
```

which will essentially do the same thing at once, without the need to specify multiple variables and arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

```
identifiers = $_GET['identifiers']
```

If you know the key names, then simply:

```
$mc_name = $identifiers['mc']['nick']
```

If you know it's the first value or the first value, then you can:

```
$mc_name = array_shift($identifiers);  // get the 'mc' array
$mc_name = array_shift($identifiers);  // get the 'nick' value
```

Not that `array_shift` will actually remove the elements from the original array.