# How can I get specific value from array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to get value of "url". How can I do this? Please help! Thanks.

```
Array(
        [value] => Array
            (
         [url] => http://localhost/azmith/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/hero-img.jpg
               ) )
```

The complete array is following:

```
    <?php

       Array(
                ["ID"] => 55,
                ["key"] => "field_5bb500e3e1d6a",
                ["label"] => "Main Banner Image",
                ["type"] => "image",
                ["value"] => Array
(
                        ["ID"] => 63,
                        ["title"] => "hero-img",
                        ["filename"] => "hero-img.jpg",
                        ["url"] => "http://localhost/azmith/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/hero-img.jpg",
                    ),
            );

    ?>
```

Comment: If it is single dimensional array you can get it like : $arr['value']['url']; Assuming $arr is your array.

Comment: no its multidimensional array @sehdev

Comment: @Faa Show us the code and full array.

Comment: @vicek i was using this $array = array("value" => array("url") ); and output was this: Array ( [value] => Array ( [0] => url ) )

Comment: i have already posted the array

Comment: i want to get value of url

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708065/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/26741946/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/40926522/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37259193/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/42275302/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/28805647/2943403

Comment: its not  @mickmakusa

Comment: wait, I have a half a million more to post.

Comment: ok i am waiting for exact

Comment: You must be joking.  I am not going to find an exact duplicate for `value` and `url`.  Your question is about as basic as it gets.  You did not read the manual, you didn't research enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

$url = $yourArrayName['value']['url'];

Comment: its not working @jitendra

Comment: Please never, ever, ever post code only answers.

Comment: i was using this $array = array("value" => array("url") );    and output was  this: Array
(
    [value] => Array
        (
            [0] => url
        )
)

Comment: @Faa Maybe your array variable name is `$array`. So try `echo $array['value']['url'];`

Comment: @vivek_23 This question is a mega duplicate, please support the closure.

Comment: yes i have tried @vivek but dont know why its not working

Comment: @mick do u have any personal problem?

Comment: @mickmackusa Did so.

Comment: @Faa You need to be more clear about your question. You already have an answer but if it's still not working, then you will have to show us your entire code.

Comment: echo $array['value']['url'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

Comment: @Faa Try to replace $yourArrayName with your array variable.

Comment: you can see vivek

Comment: @Faa That's what I said earlier. Try `echo $myArray['value']['url'];`

Comment: @Faa Your variable happened to be `$myArray` instead of `$array`.

Comment: vivek i don't have $myArray in code plz see

Comment: @Faa If you don't use `@` before my name, I won't be notified. Secondly, you edited your post and removed `$myArray`. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yes that editing was automatic so i removed $myArray @vivek_23

Comment: https://prnt.sc/l25l8l @vivek_23 check this is the code screeenshot

Comment: https://prnt.sc/l25n5t   @vivek_23

Comment: @Faa What is above line 122 in that pic?